# How to apply copyright template to all source code in Spring Tool Suite STS?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am using STS 3.7.1. I found a few guides on how to apply templates and copyrights content to all project files for different versions of eclipse. However, so far none of them works for STS 3.7.x. Any suggestion?

What I tried:

1. copyright wizard. Cannot be found now, retired?
2. Releng too. Cannot be found now, retired?
3. eclipse fix copyright tool. Cannot found in STS, maybe they refer it same as Releng?

Comment: What did you try? How exactly it didn't work? Exceptions in the log?

Comment: Releng Tools seem to be there for 4.5.x and for the new 4.6. You just need to install Releng Tools from update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.5 (Help -> Intstall New Software...) Releng Tools at the bottom of the list. There are Releng Tools availabel for 4.6 as well via update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe tools you have tried to find... they are *not* included by default into STS (nor Eclipse). But you have to install them as optional add-on.

For example the "Copyright Wizard" can be installed from the "Eclipse Market Place". I found it here:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/copyright-wizard

According to recent feeback posted on the market-place entry, this plugin still works fine on the currently latest Eclipse release (4.5).

To install from marketplace the easiest is to use the Eclipse Marketplace Client which you can open from STS (or Eclipse) "Help" menu.